# How to add onClosed event listener from Chrome notifications API for chrome extension in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering on how to add a listener on whenever a Chrome notification is closed. Here's my code:

```
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function (notifId, byUser) {
  console.log(byUser);
  console.log("notification closed");
});
```

I'm simply trying to log the event for now, and I can't seem to understand why nothing logs when I close the notification. I've checked the official documentation and it seems like I'm calling it correctly.

After a certain amount of time (I think like 20-30 minutes?) it seems to finally register all the closed events at once as per this screenshot of the log, perhaps accounting for all the times I closed it? [image]

I should also mention that the other chrome notification events work fine, that is `chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener()` works and so does `chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener()`.

The only way I can seem to "force" call the listener to execute is by calling
`chrome.notifications.onClosed.dispatch();` which proves the listener works, it just isn't listening, haha.

Comment: This API is inherently bugged, see https://crbug.com/1212142.